# Creating Mobile Service Rest API in Azure and consuming it

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js, azure

I have published a Web Site to Azure. The site functionality is written in Js (with Backbone), and currently it just uses browser's web storage for data persistence. I'd like to create a  mobile service with a SQL database and consume REST API and use that to populate and save data from my website.

What exactly does Azure do here out of the box for me ? 
I found this article: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj677199.aspx

It says that for a Get request I use something like:

https://.azure-mobile.net/tables/

So in my JS file that populates the view (currently by reading from localstorage), I should just make a request from that url and specify service name and table name where the data is stored?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the data you service return you should create a model/collection :

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: 'yourServiceUrlHere'
});
```

Or

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults : { ... }
});

var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: 'yourServiceUrlHere',
    model: MyModel
});
```

and assign this model/collection to your view :

```
// In your view
initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
    // Or this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);
    ....
}
```